Can difference quotient sets be nowhere dense?
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and consider the difference quotient set $$D_f = \left\{\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} : (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, y > x\right\}$$

Can $D_f$ be nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ for non-linear $f$?

We can verify that the answer is false for $f$ continuous, since in that case $D_f$ is the continuous image of the connected set $\{y>x\}$ under $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$, hence connected (i.e., an interval) which is not nowhere dense unless $D_f$ is a singleton (which only happens for linear $f$).
But $D_f$ need not be connected in general. Indeed, consider $f = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Then it is easy to check $D_f = \{0\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$, which is not connected (in fact, totally disconnected).

Some thoughts: My answer here shows that the difference quotient can be made to be contained in any pre-fixed co-countable set, and $f$ can be even be measurable in this case. More generally, assuming CH, by an argument similar to this answer of mine, the difference quotient can be made to be contained in any pre-fixed co-null set or co-meager set. Neither of these directly helps here, but it does show you can put some significant constraints on the difference quotient set.

It may help : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72800/every-real-function-has-a-dense-set-on-which-its-restriction-is-continuous

@Cactus Noah Schweber has tried applying that in a now-deleted answer. It doesn’t work. The main issue is that continuous on a dense set does not mean you can restrict to a dense set then extend the restricted function to some interval. The latter step requires uniform continuity in some interval, which may not be true.

I still couldn’t figure this out, but let me mention that my answer here can be adapted to prove, under CH (or Martin’s Axiom), that the difference quotient set can be made to lie within any pre-fixed co-null set. Since a co-null set can be meager, at least $D_f$ being meager is then possible.

For the sake of future reference (as my previous comments on this were all under now-deleted answers), and as alluded to in my reply to Cactus’s comment, the following approach using Blumberg’s theorem (which says any function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ restricts to a continuous function on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$) does not work: Restrict $f$ to a dense subset $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ on which it is continuous, then choose some interval $(a, b)$ and extend $f|_{D \cap (a, b)}$ to some continuous $g$ on $(a, b)$, then argue using this extended $g$. The reason this does not work…

… is because it might be impossible to extend $f|{D \cap (a, b)}$ to a continuous $g$ on $(a, b)$, for any nontrivial interval $(a, b)$, as that requires uniform continuity instead of just continuity. For an explicit example, pick a closed totally disconnected $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ of cardinality continuum (say, the Cantor set), and let $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $A$. Then whatever $D$ is, $f|{D \cap (a, b)}$ has range in $A$. If $f|_{D \cap (a, b)}$ can be extended to a continuous $g$ on $(a, b)$, then because $D$ is dense and $A$ is closed, $g$ must have range in $A$…

… But $A$ is totally disconnected, so $g$ is constant. But $f$ is a bijection, so $D \cap (a, b)$ is a singleton, which contradicts it being dense in $(a, b)$. (Also worth mentioning: any nowhere dense set has as its complement a set with dense interior, so in particular it cannot be co-null, so my approach to trying to construct counterexamples, mentioned in my July 5 comment, cannot work either.)

@DavidGao Answer posted for this, which I haven't checked in detail since I'm a bit busy. Thought I'd ping you since you seem very interested.

@MathematicsStudent1122 Thanks for the heads up. I tried to read the proof but I don’t fully understand the argument for Lemma 2, so I couldn’t judge the correctness of the answer. I’ll leave this to others who may be more familiar with the techniques used.

If $A \subset \mathbf{R}$ and $f: A \to \mathbf{R}$, then we put $D(f) = \{(f(y) - f(x))/(y - x) : x, y \in A, x \neq y\}$.
Theorem 1. If $f: [a, b] \to \mathbf{R}$ is not linear, then $D(f)$ is dense in a nondegenerate interval.
Lemma 2. Suppose $A \subset \mathbf{R}$ and $g: A \to \mathbf{R}$ is Lipschitz. If $D(g)$ is nowhere dense, then $g$ equals a linear function a.e.
Proof. Let $F$ denote the closure of $A$, and let $h$ be an extension of $g$ to $\mathbf{R}$ as a Lipshitz function. It's easy to see that $D(h|_F)$ is covered by the closure of $D(g)$, and thus $D(h|_F)$ is nowhere dense. The function $h$, being Lipschitz, is a.e. differentiable. Then there is a set $E \subset F$ such that $\lambda(F \setminus E) = 0$, every point of $E$ is a point of density of $E$, and $h$ is differentiable at every point of $E$.
Let $m(x, y)$ denote the difference quotient $(h(x) - h(y))/(x - y)$. We prove that if $x_1, x_2 \in E$ are distinct, then at least one of $h'(x_1)$ and $h'(x_2)$ equals $m(x_1, x_2)$. Suppose this is not true, and let $x_1, x_2 \in E$ be such that each of $h'(x_1)$ and $h'(x_2)$ differs from $m_0$. We reach a contradiction be showing that $D(h|_E)$ contains an interval. Let $e$ denote the tangent line of $\text{Graph}\,h$ at the point $(x_1, h(x_1))$.
Let $\pi_m(p)$ denote the projection of the point $p \in \mathbf{R}^2$ onto $e$ in the direction of $m$. That is, let $\pi_m(p) \in e$ be such that the slope of the line going through the points $\pi_m(p)$ and $p$ equals $m$ (and $\pi_m(p) = p$ if $p \in e$). Let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint neighborhoods of $(x_1, h(x_1))$ and $(x_2, h(x_2))$. It's easy to see that if $m \neq h'(x_1)$, then $(x_1, h(x_1))$ is a point of density of the set $\pi_m((\text{Graph}\, h) \cap U)$. Similarly, $\pi_m((x_2, h(x_2)))$ is a point of density of the set $\pi_m((\text{Graph}\, h) \cap V)$ for every $m \neq h'(x_2)$. Therefore, if $m$ is close enough to $m_0$, then $\pi_m((\text{Graph}\, h) \cap U) \cap \pi_m((\text{Graph}\, h) \cap V) \neq \emptyset$. Clearly, if $z$ is an element of the intersection and $z = \pi_m((z_1, h(z_1))) = \pi_m((z_2, h(z_2)))$, then $m(z_1, z_2) = m$, and $m \in D(h|_E)$. Therefore, $D(h|_E)$ contains the interval $(m_0 - \eta, m_0 + \eta)$ for a small enough $\eta > 0$. But this is impossible, as $D(h|_E) \subset D(h|_F)$ and $D(h|_F)$ is nowhere dense.
Let $x_1 \in A_1$ be fixed, and let $e$ denote the tangent line of $\text{Graph}\, h$ at the point $(x_1, h(x_1))$. We show that $\text{Graph}\, h|_E \subset e$, which will prove the statement of the lemma.
Suppose $\text{Graph}\, h|_E \not\subset e$, and let $x_2 \in E$ be such that $(x_2, h(x_2)) \notin e$. Then $h'(x_1) \neq m(x_1, x_2)$, and thus $h'(x_2) = m(x_1, x_2)$. If a point $x_3 \in E$ is close enough to $x_1$, then $m(x_2, x_3) \neq m(x_1, x_2) = h'(x_2)$, and thus $h'(x_3) = m(x_2, x_3)$. Fix such an $x_3$, and choose a point $x_4$ close enough to $x_1$. Then $h'(x_3) = m(x_2, x_3)$ and $h'(x_4) = m(x_2, x_4)$ are different from $m(x_3, x_4)$, a contradiction.
Proof of the theorem. If $D(f)$ is everywhere dense, then we are done. Therefore, we may assume that there is an open interval $I$ with $I \cap D(f) = \emptyset$. Replacing $f$ by $f + c \cdot x$ with a suitable $c$, we may assume that $I = (-\delta, \delta)$ with a $\delta > 0$. Then $0 \notin D(f)$, and thus $f$ is injective.
Let $A = f([a, b])$ be the range of $f$, and put $g = f^{-1}$. Then $D(g) \subset \left[-\frac{1}{\delta}, \frac{1}{\delta}\right]$, and thus $g : A \to \mathbf{R}$ is Lipschitz. Clearly, it is enough to show that $D(g)$ is not nowhere dense. Suppose it is. Then, by Lemma 2, $g$ is linear a.e.; that is, there is a set $A_1 \subset A$ such that $g|_{A_1}$ is linear, and $\lambda(A \setminus A_1) = 0$.
Since $g$ is Lipschitz, the set $B = g(A \setminus A_1)$ is of measure zero. Also, $f$ is linear on the set $g(A_1) = g(A) \setminus g(A \setminus A_1) = [a, b] \setminus B$. Since $\lambda(B) = 0$, the set $g(A_1)$ is dense in $[a, b]$. Since $f$ is not linear, there is a point $x_0 \in [a, b]$ such that $(x_0, f(x_0))$ is not on the line containing $\text{Graph}\, f|_{g(A_1)}$. Then the set $\left\{\frac{f(x_0) - f(x)}{x - x_0} : x \in g(A_1)\right\}$ is dense in an interval, and then so is $D(f)$.
